# Unable to Store image path into database using codeigniter - Student Registration

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image]

I am working on a school management system. I am storing student information with their image. I am using this code so my all information is update in data base but image path is not getting in the database. I am unable to find the error. please help me. I have already load the upload library.
I want to store student information to data base. I want to store student image in to **upload** folder.

my directory structure is

- application
- upload

My controller code is

```
public function saveStudent() {
    $data = array();

    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => '/upload/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
        $fileName = $this->upload->data();
        $image = $fileName['file_path'];
        $data = array(
            'student_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'class' => $this->input->post('class'),
            'section' => $this->input->post('section'),
            'addressline1' => $this->input->post('addressline1'),
            'addressline2' => $this->input->post('addressline2'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
            'religion' => $this->input->post('religion'),
            'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'addmission_date' => $this->input->post('adddate'),
            'registrationdate' => $this->input->post('registration'),
            'fathername' => $this->input->post('fathername'),
            'foccu' => $this->input->post('foccu'),
            'fquali' => $this->input->post('fquali'),
            'fmobile' => $this->input->post('fmobile'),
            'fdob' => $this->input->post('fdob'),
            'mothername' => $this->input->post('mothername'),
            'moccu' => $this->input->post('moccu'),
            'mquali' => $this->input->post('mquali'),
            'mmobile' => $this->input->post('mmobile'),
            'mdob' => $this->input->post('mdob'),
            'lastschool' => $this->input->post('lastschool'),
            'lastexam' => $this->input->post('lastexam'),
            'lastresult' => $this->input->post('lastresult'),
            'lastmark' => $this->input->post('lastmark'),
            'board' => $this->input->post('board'),
            'adharcard' => $this->input->post('adharcard'),
            'TC' => $this->input->post('TC'),
            'CC' => $this->input->post('CC'),
            'result' => $this->input->post('result'),
            'dobc' => $this->input->post('dobc'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'photo' => $image // add this for image
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert('student', $data);
}
```

please help me i want to upload image to upload folder and store path to database.

Comment: Let's debug it a little bit: please add this line "var_dump($filename);"
After this line "$fileName = $this->upload->data();"
And show us the output of that.
The var_dump function shows the content of any type of variable or object

Comment: Also, please edit the question to include only the relevant code - the code of the rest of your form is not necessary and just makes it less likely that the community will read the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please anyone help...!

Answer (score 0):

Just try this method when the upload success

```
$path = $this->upload->data('full_path');
```

To debug the name just die from here and check `die($path)`